# How to enable Exception Handling on XCode 3.2.3?

Tags: c++, xcode, gdb

How to enable exceptions in XCode - 3.2.3. Is there any flag like I should enable for the compiler for exception handling? Tried googling but didn't find enough information on XCode with `C++` !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int i=5,j=0;
        int res = i/j;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& exe) 
    {
        std::cerr<< exe.what();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout<< "\n Default Exception Handler \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Loading program into debugger…
>   Program loaded.
>   run
>   [Switching to process 1332]
>   Running…
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_ARITHMETIC”.
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   kill
>   Current language:  auto; currently c++
>   quit
>   The Debugger has exited with status 0.(gdb)

Edit :Though the reason seems to be different, to anyone, this figure might be helpful in future.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by zero does not raise a C++ exception. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure exception handling is on by default, but I don't think division by zero actually generates an exception. If you want to make sure they are on though, just go to your project or target settings, and search for "exception"; there's a checkbox called "Enable C++ Exceptions".

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is enabled by default. Above discussions is the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

A CPU exception such as an arithmetic exception like divide by zero above is not a C++ exception. People who have only ever used Microsoft Visual C++ often get confused by this, since Microsoft added a non-standard extension which allows CPU exceptions to be treated as C++ exceptions, but this is not the norm and is of course not portable.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to handle the exception is proper ... that will work in the exception flows.

Not: The EXC_ARITHMETIC (devision by 0) is not an exception it is a signal -- so you have to use signal handlers to handle this.