# C++ exception not caught in XCode iOS project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, exception

I created a C++ library. I am using it in an iOS application. I thought of handling exceptions in C++ library and in order to test this I created a test scheme and called the c++ function from it. In the c++ function I intentionally wrote erroneous code.

```
try 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 10/i;
} 
catch(std::exception &e){
    printf("Exception : %s\n",e.what());
}
```

But the exception is never caught and the application breaks at - int j = 10/i;

Please tell me, how can I add exception handling to my c++ code in this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK division by zero is Undefined Behavior and no exception will ever be thrown.

Comment: -1 code sample does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't throw an exception when a division by zero is encountered (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error) other questions)! Quoting Stroustrup:

> low-level events, such as arithmetic overflows and divide by zero, are
>   assumed to be handled by a dedicated lower-level mechanism rather than
>   by exceptions. This enables C++ to match the behaviour of other
>   languages when it comes to arithmetic. It also avoids the problems
>   that occur on heavily pipelined architectures where events such as
>   divide by zero are asynchronous.

*"The Design and Evolution of C++" (Addison Wesley, 1994)*

So you will have to handle this case yourself - you'll have to check each potential divisor before division and handle it.

Comment: I am new to c++ and thus did not know this.