# why destructor is not called in this class

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I have a simple class as follow in test.h

```
class test
{
        test()
        {
            std::cout<<"constructor called"<<std::endl;
        }
        static test m_test;
        ~test()
        {
            std::cout<<"I am here"<<std::endl;
        }

};
```

and the static member is defined in test.cpp as:

```
test test::m_test;
```

The main has nothing :

```
main()
{

}
```

and I can see in the output:

```
constructor called
I am here
```

which is good. Now I am adding a bit of code that generate an exception like this:

```
 main()
 {
     for(int i=-1; i<1; i++)
     {
         i=1/i;   // this line generate an exception and close the application.
     }
}
```

In this case the destructor is not called. and I can only see that the constructor is called.

Why this is happening?

How can I make sure that if an expectation thrown and application crashed, the destructor is called? Assuming that I can only change my test class and not the main application.

Comment: Aren't destructors only called on instantiated classes?

Comment: If your application crashes, what makes you think that a function such as a destructor will survive the crash?

Comment: It is called on ideone : http://ideone.com/5a8e20

Comment: its platform dependent, on win32 it will be a SEH exception and will simply crash and burn at the divide by zero

Comment: @Nawaz That's because ideone compiled it with optimizations, which removed the useless `i=1/i` line. Change it to `std::cout<<1/i` to force it to execute.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, stack unwinding?

Answer (score 1):

Divide by zero is not an exception! It is not possible to catch it as it is a hardware signal to the operating system to interrupt your program.

Read more here:

[C++ : Catch a divide by zero error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error)

In order to throw a random exception you can just do

`throw std::runtime_error("Oh no!");`

but make sure you catch the thrown exception in the calling code with:

```
try {
   codeThatThrowsException();
} catch(const std::runtime_error& e) {
   std::cout << "An exception was thrown: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not in C++ anyway. Don't generalize.

Comment: @Blindy: It's tagged C++

Comment: How can I generate an exception to check that destructor is called?

Comment: @mans You can just throw an exception. But for stack unwinding to take place correctly, you need to have a try block around exception-throwing code anyway.