# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector Abort trap: 6. any help would be awesome, thank you

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve fractional knapsack problem, for now logic aside can anyone suggest me or explain me what is happening here? I never seen this runtime-error before, any help would be awesome, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
bool myfunction(int a, int b){return(a>b);}

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values) {
  double value = 0.0;
  vector<double> prop(weights.size());
  for(int i=0;i<=weights.size();i++){
      double Pvalue = (weights.at(i))/(values.at(i));
      prop.push_back(Pvalue);
  }
  std::sort(prop.begin(),prop.end(),myfunction);
  for(int it =0;it<=values.size();it++){
      while(capacity >=prop.at(it)){
          value+=prop.at(it);
          capacity-=prop.at(it);
      }
  }
  return value;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int capacity;
  std::cin >> n >> capacity;
  vector<int> values(n);
  vector<int> weights(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
  }

  double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values);

  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, `(weights.at(i))/(values.at(i))` is doing integer division with truncation and will lead to getting wrong answer.

Comment: In addition to the above if `values.at(i)` is 0, the program will likely crash. integer division by zero is usually immediately fatal. Might even be mandated to be immediately fatal by the C++ Standard, but I've never had cause to look it up and confirm it.

Comment: [Just looked it up](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4) divide by zero is undefined behaviour. Most likely the CPU will raise an error that you can try to intercept and handle ([almost certainly futile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error)) or outright kill the program, but it's [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) so you could get a plague of "Nasal Demons" instead. Note that you might not even get an error message saying it happened. The program may just seem to stop without giving you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `v` is a vector, only elements `v[0]` to `v[v.size() - 1]` are available and `v[v.size()]` is out-of-range.

Therefore,

```
for(int i=0;i<=weights.size();i++)
```

and

```
for(int it =0;it<=values.size();it++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<weights.size();i++)
```

and

```
for(int it =0;it<values.size();it++)
```

(use `<` instead of `<=`)

Comment: In general `<=` in a `for` loop exit condition should be viewed with suspicion. It's not always wrong, but it is often enough to deserve a second or third glance to make sure it isn't. Then you probably want to document it so folks in the future won't waste time re-inspecting or worse, "Fix" the bug.

Comment: Yeah and if OP wants to read on it, "half open interval" is a good search

Comment: By doing those i got rid of the error thankfully, but still the program is not yielding any o/p

Comment: @SamFrancis The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run a program on your terms and view what happens as it happens. If, while stepping through the program, you spot the program doing something you didn't expect, you probably found a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<=weights.size();i++)
```

Will access the array one past the end of it. You need to use `< weights.size()` because c++ arrays are 0-based.